# Information on this SMD transistor?

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount

I'm repairing a board; a SOT-23 transistor has come off and a leg has broken off. It's marked with "C5UKE" but I can not find information anywhere online to find a replacement for it.

[image: image of the transistor]

Can anyone identify this transistor?

Answer (score 0):

In most applications, the specific transistor parameters are not critical.

1. If the board only uses 3.3 V or 5 V, then the voltage rating probably doesn't matter.
2. Figure out if it is an NPN or a PNP. If one terminal is connected to GND, it's likely an NPN (and that's the emitter). If one has a larger value resistor driving it (perhaps 100 Ω - 10k), that is likely the base.

Comment: I would start by figuring out if it's even a transistor. SOT-23 is a common package for diodes and three-terminal ICs (tiny linear regulators, TL431s, etc) too, so it's not necessarily safe to assume it's a transistor. And even then, it may be a FET, not a BJT.

Comment: I assume its a FET given that the base leg has a much thinner trace on the board. However I'll look around online to see if I can find a matching SOT-23 package which might not be a transistor. The problem I had was that there was no results for those markings anywhere, so narrowing the search to a specific IC won't help me much

Comment: @QuickishFM Can you edit your question to add a photo of the PCB near the mystery component so that we can see what else is in the vicinity, and therefore could be connected to it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have this board anymore.